# Can sqldf be used to import the data of an already existing table in a database into a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, postgresql, sqldf

Today, for the first time I discovered **sqldf** package which I found to be very useful and convenient. Here is what the documentation says about the package:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqldf/versions/0.4-11

> sqldf is an R package for runing SQL statements on R data frames,
> optimized for convenience. The user simply specifies an SQL statement
> in R using data frame names in place of table names and a database
> with appropriate table layouts/schema is automatically created, the
> data frames are automatically loaded into the database, the specified
> SQL statement is performed, the result is read back into R and the
> database is deleted all automatically behind the scenes making the
> database's existence transparent to the user who only specifies the
> SQL statement.

So if I understand correctly, some data.frame which contains data stored in the RAM of the computer is mapped into a database on the disk temporarily as a table, then the calculation or whatever the query is supposed to do will be done and finally the result is returned back to R and all that was temporarily created in the database goes away as it never existed.

My question is, does it work other way around? Meaning, that assuming there is already a table let's say named `my_table` (just an example) in the database (I use PostgreSQL), is there any way to import its data from the database into a data.frame in R via **sqldf**? Because, currently the only way that I know is RPostgreSQL.

Comment: You can run a select statement to retrieve data.  There is info in ?sqldf and in FAQ#12 on https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your help. It works! I explained (see the answer below) where was mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to G. Grothendieck for the answer. Indeed it is perfectly possible to select data from already existing tables in the database. My mistake was that I was thinking that the name of the dataframe and the corresponding table must always be the same, whereas if I understand correctly, this is only the case when a data.frame data is mapped to a temporary table in the database. As a result when I tried to select data, I had an error message saying that a table with the same name already existed in my database.

Anyway, just as a test to see whether this works, I did the following in PostgreSQL (**postgres** user and **test** database which is owned by postgres)

```
test=# create table person(fname text, lname text, email text);
CREATE TABLE
test=# insert into person(fname, lname, email) values ('fname-01', 'lname-01', 'fname-01.lname-01@gmail.com'), ('fname-02', 'lname-02', 'fname-02.lname-02@gmail.com'), ('fname-03', 'lname-03', 'fname-03.lname-03@gmail.com');
INSERT 0 3
test=# select * from person;
  fname   |  lname   |            email            
----------+----------+-----------------------------
 fname-01 | lname-01 | fname-01.lname-01@gmail.com
 fname-02 | lname-02 | fname-02.lname-02@gmail.com
 fname-03 | lname-03 | fname-03.lname-03@gmail.com
(3 rows)

test=#
```

Then I wrote the following in R

```
options(sqldf.RPostgreSQL.user = "postgres", 
  sqldf.RPostgreSQL.password = "postgres",
  sqldf.RPostgreSQL.dbname = "test",
  sqldf.RPostgreSQL.host = "localhost", 
  sqldf.RPostgreSQL.port = 5432)
###
###
library(tidyverse)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(sqldf)
###
###
result_df <- sqldf("select * from person")
```

And indeed we can see that **result_df** contains the data stored in the table **person**.

```
> result_df
     fname    lname                       email
1 fname-01 lname-01 fname-01.lname-01@gmail.com
2 fname-02 lname-02 fname-02.lname-02@gmail.com
3 fname-03 lname-03 fname-03.lname-03@gmail.com
> 
>
```